# SQL WHERE clause performance issue

Tags: t-sql

I have a proc that I need to filter. I create a table var with INT records, (1,2)
in this example, based on a parameter. If I use it in the WHERE clause, it's super slow. A hardcoded version is super fast. Why?

```
AND PKRequestStatus IN (SELECT PKRequestStatus FROM @StatusTable) -- Super slow

AND PKRequestStatus IN (1,2) -- Super fast
```

Comment: Please try to change to temp table `AND PKRequestStatus IN (SELECT PKRequestStatus FROM #StatusTable) ` Probably the cardinality is estimated to 1 in subquery.

Comment: These will generate different  plans. Look at the plans and make decision.

Comment: I'll try that. In the meantime, I enclosed the select in another select * from and filtered that. Worked like a champ. I'll dig into the query plans and see why.

Comment: In another select * may not be better tomorrow or with different data.  What is the server?

Answer (score 1):

Hard coded the query optimizer has more information.

Put a primary key on the table variable and use a join.  The primary key lets the optimizer know that it can stop once it hits a match and it is an index.

```
FROM tt 
JOIN @StatusTable st 
  ON tt.PKRequestStatus = st.ID
```

If there are a lot of values then use #temp (with primary key) over table variable.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
    AND PKRequestStatus IN (SELECT DISTINCT PKRequestStatus FROM @StatusTable)
```